# Заполнение данных из контекста данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть отношение многие ко многим.

```
public class MyIdentityRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string AltName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public IList<PermissionRole> PermissionRoles { get; set; } 

    public MyIdentityRole() : base()
    {
        PermissionRoles = new List<PermissionRole>();
    }

    public MyIdentityRole(string name, string altName)
   : base(name)
    {
        AltName = altName;
    }
}
public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PermissionId")]
    public IList<PermissionRole> PermissionRoles { get; set; }

    public Permission()
    {
        PermissionRoles = new List<PermissionRole>();
    }
}
public class PermissionRole
{
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public string RoleId { get; set; }

    public MyIdentityRole Role { get; set; }
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationContext : IdentityDbContext<User, MyIdentityRole, string>
{
    public DbSet<PermissionRole> PermissionsRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PermissionRole>()
            .HasKey(pr => new { pr.PermissionId, pr.RoleId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PermissionRole>()
            .HasOne(pr => pr.Permission)
            .WithMany(p => p.PermissionRoles);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PermissionRole>()
            .HasOne(pr => pr.Role)
            .WithMany(r => r.PermissionRoles);
    }
}
```

Вопрос у меня в следующем, у роли есть свойство `PermissionRoles`, когда я к нему обращаюсь, оно пустое, хотя сопоставление в БД есть, то есть запись. Вопрос, должна ли модель при создании при помощи EF Core заполняться сама данными о `PermissionRoles` или мне в конструкторе модели надо лепить подобного рода костыль:

```
public MyIdentityRole(ApplicationContext context) : base()
{
   PermissionRoles = context.PermissionsRoles.Where(pr => pr.Role == this).ToList();
}
```

Comment: `var permissionsWithFilledRoles = context.Permissions.Include(p=>p.PermissionRoles)` ?

Comment: @tym32167 Работает)) Я думал что там под капотам магия должна происходить. Include эти там внутри join происходит?

Comment: Думаю да, но я не проверял, какие именно запросы формируются - у контекста вроде есть опция для трассировки запросов, ну или в профайлере вашей БД это можн глянуть